# Leaflet.js Display line or circle depending on number of points provided

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
function filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs) {
var result = [];

if (latlngs.length > 0) {
  result.push(latlngs[0]);
}

for (var i = 1; i < latlngs.length; i += 1) {
  if (!L.latLng(latlngs[i]).equals(latlngs[i - 1])) {
    result.push(latlngs[i]);
  }
}
return result;
}

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/geojson/routes",
dataType: 'json',
async: true,
success: function(latlngs) {
  if (filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs).length >= 2){
    console.log("multiple points")
    var filtered = filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs);
    var Geodesic = L.geodesic([filtered], {
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'navy',
      steps: 200,
    }).addTo(mymap);
  }
  else{
    console.log("single point")
    var filtered = filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs);
    var Circle = L.circle(filtered.slice(0), filtered.slice(1), {
      radius: 1000,
    }).addTo(mymap);
    }
  }
  });
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: this._latlng is null
```

I think it's because L.circle() isn't getting the correct data although `filtered` is an array with a lat and a lng - instead of slicing `filtered` I've also just used `filtered` as an argument.

I currently get a point - based on another script with a blank map.

The purpose is to draw a circle if only one point is provided and several lines if multiple points are provided.

Thanks to anyone that looks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misuse the `L.circle` factory. It takes only 2 arguments: the position (coordinates) and options.

You might also have become confused about what you store in your `filtered` variable, i.e. what your `filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions` function returns: it is an array of coordinates. Whereas you seem to try extracting a latitude at index 0 and a longitude at index 1.

There is also no need to `slice` your array if you do not change it.

```js
L.circle(filtered[0], {
  radius: 1000,
}).addTo(mymap);
```

BTW you can DRY your code by caching the result of `filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs)` at the beginning of your success callback, instead of calling it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it worked like a charm.